# How can I rate the question according to the difficulty?

Tags: data-mining, prediction, algorithms, item-response-theory

I have a set of problems to analyze from a programming contest. My work is to rate the question according to its difficulty *(easy,medium,hard)* by analyzing the `submission rate`,`accepted solutions rate` and `failed solutions rate` of the participants. Do I need any more parameters to analyze the difficulty and which algorithm should I use?

Edit #1:

Rare Case

What if a problem with highest difficulty has no submissions at all? How can this case be evaluated?

Edit #2:

About the contest

It is an online competitive programming contest like ACM ICPC. Questions are available to all the participants (all questions). They can start from any question. There will be 10-12 questions max. There is no submission limit for the questions. You can submit until your answer gets accepted.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the contest? Do _all_ participant see _all_ the problems? Do we have the number of submissions per question per participant?

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon Ok I will include those in my question.

Comment: Do you only have the rates for each question or do you have the data for each contestant? If you have the data for each contestant such whether or not he scored on a question, then we could rate the difficulty such as the average total score of those whose solution were accepted.

Comment: Please illustrate your data with a toy example.

Comment: Are the questions presented in a random order or always in the same order?

Comment: @jbowman What do you mean presented?All the questions are visible to all the participants.

Comment: Not simultaneously, however the eye can only see one at a time.  Unless every contestant attempts every question, then you would expect questions farther down the list to get higher non-response rates.  Also, because people do get mentally tired when programming, if the questions are always presented in the same order,  "difficulty" becomes confounded with "where on the list" the question is.  Random ordering of questions avoids both of these problems.

Comment: @jbowman Yes the questions are randomly ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not any label for the problem, you face an unsupervised learning problem. You can use clustering methods such as k-means (with k=3) to group the questions into three groups, where the problems in each group are similar to each other and dissimilar to questions in other groups. Each question is represented by a vector containing the number of submissions, accepted, and failed. After clustering, you can determine the difficulty level of the questions in each group, by investigating a small number of questions in each group.

Comment: But there is still a problem. Consider a question with highest difficulty level and there are no submissions for that. How can this method rate such a problem?

Comment: No submission is a clue of the difficulty of the problem. When you cluster your problems, the problems with a low number of submissions are probably placed in the same clusters. Maybe you should consider more than three clusters and then, merge some clusters by hand.

Comment: You could also add a dimension for "non-response".  I'd probably go with "non-response", "accepted" and "failed" as three dimensions instead.